# Why does bash say No such file or directory when the file is on the path

Tags: linux, bash

So I uninstalled cmake, and reinstalled it with an updated version, and the path is correct, and the file is there, but whenever I try to run cmake, bash echoes `-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory`

```
pi@raspberrypi /usr/local/bin $ dir
cmake  cpack  ctest  indiecity

pi@raspberrypi /usr/local/bin $ export | grep PATH
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to type `hash -r` to rebuild the shell's command hash table. 
It still "remembers" having found `cmake` in `/usr/bin`,
so it just goes there, rather than searching through the search path again.

Or you could start a new shell. 
Or logout and login again, or reboot.